# Why does base64 code changes when inserted into mongodb?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, base64, cryptojs

I am working on generating unique email links for my users, trying to generate a code bye concatenating the user email and the Date timestamp.

The code generated looks like this

```
bUBzLnBvazE0NjM2ODc3MDg0MTA=3D
```

while in the mongodb it doesn't have 3D in it,   `bUBzLnBvazE0NjM2ODc3MDg0MTA=`, and that's why URLs don't work.

I am using cryptoJS to encode string into base64.

```
const BASE_SERVER_URL = "http://localhost:3000/";
const INVITE_URL = BASE_SERVER_URL+"login/";

let uniqueCode = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(pmGroupUser.email+Date.now()));
    let emailText = "Hello " + pmGroupUser.first_name +  " click the following url to register your self ";
    emailText += INVITE_URL;
    emailText += uniqueCode;


        Meteor.call('sendEmail',"to", "from","Subject", emailText, (err, res) => {
            if(!err) {
                Invites.insert({
                    code: uniqueCode
                });
            }
        });
```

Comment: `bUBzLnBvazE0NjM2ODc3MDg0MTA=3D` is not a valid Base64-encoding, because nothing can come after the padding character (`=`). How are you printing this value? CryptoJS' Base64-encoding should work correctly, so this probably has nothing to do with CryptoJS.

Comment: I don't know but if you log uniqueCode before the meteor call it gets printed

Comment: @ArtjomB. please see the code, I have added the text sent in the email

Comment: I still don't see how you print it and where you read it from, but then it could be my inexperience with meteor.